# how to resize physical android screen from terminal/shell

Tags: android, resize, adb, screen, tablet

A while ago, I was able to resize the screens on Android. For example, I had a Xoom, and was able to run a command from ADB which shrunk it down to a 7" screen (leaving a black border around it). Granted, it was a little buggy because the home/back/app-switch buttons disappeared, but I know it's possible. It's a 1 line command where I input the new screen resolution in X and Y pixels for the Xoom.

I was wondering if anyone was familiar with this, and knows how to do it.

(and if anyone says it's not possible, I can assure you it is)

(and I want to do this so I can test apps in various screen sizes on my Nexus 10, and I'd prefer not using an emulator)

Comment: Another use for that is when you have your screen cracked on one side corner, with 80% working touches. You can resize it then and have working screen again ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe it is:

```
adb shell am display-size
```

but i am away from a computer to try it. An example use would be:

```
adb shell am display-size 640x480
```

Comment: To reset the screen size use `adb shell am display-size reset`.

Comment: Is the way to stretch that piece of screen to full size?
I have 9.7 Retina 2048x1536 and I prefer to change resolution to 1024x768 but have only a piece of screen in left upper corner...

Comment: I get  error `/system/bin/sh: wm: not found`. Why? look at my question in http://stackoverflow.com/q/30839523/779408

Answer (score 63):

An update to this answer for Jelly Bean 4.3 [from Android dev Adam Powell on Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AdamWPowell/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG) (link found via [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322631/2577986)):

> In Android 4.3 these options moved from the "am" command (ActivityManager) to the "wm" command (WindowManager). Type "adb shell wm" for details.

So you can now run  on 4.3 devices:

`adb shell wm size 1280x800` or whatever size or `reset`

and

`adb shell wm density 480` or whatever density or `reset`

Just make sure the screen is not currently displaying at the moment you run the command.

Comment: Any way to set this as a property in /system/build.prop?

Comment: @Paul Harris has anyone been able to change the size/density and still show the back button?  Is there another command that forces it to show?  Also, when I do a reset, the back button is only visible in portrait mode?

Comment: I get  error `/system/bin/sh: wm: not found`. Why? please look at my question in http://stackoverflow.com/q/30839523/779408

Comment: Is there any way to call this from Android code at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

you can also change the resolution via android terminal, just type "wm size 720x1280" for example.