# Android: Using a tablet to emulate other devices?

Tags: android, emulation, resolution, tablet, dpi

I'm thinking of investing in a Google Nexus 10 as my tablet of choice for testing my apps on - I just wondered is it possible to emulate other devices screen resolutions?  As the nexus 10 has such a high res and DPI, I would like to be able to run my app on it in say, an 800 x 480 screen etc...

I would like to do this if possible because it would be faster than using the emulator and would support multi-touch.  It seems like a no-brainer, but is it actually possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a way - a post of G+ from Adam Powell (one of the Android devs) explains it nicely:

https://plus.google.com/u/0/107708120842840792570/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG

Basically there are some ADB commands you can use to change the resolution a device displays:

```
adb shell am display-size
```

and

```
adb shell am display-density
```

For devices 4.3+, the command is slightly different:

```
adb shell wm display-density
adb shell wm dislay-size
```

Comment: It's a pretty awesome tip - you are clever to actually ask the right question (I had never even thought this possible before I saw this tip on G+).

Comment: running the second command I get Unknown command: display-density, using android 4.03

Comment: Adam Powell updated the G+ post at the bottom - tl;dr, in Android 4.3+ the commands are now in 'adb shell wm' and changed names slightly: 'adb shell wm size' and 'adb shell wm density'

Answer (score 14):

An update to this answer for Jelly Bean 4.3 [from Android dev Adam Powell on Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AdamWPowell/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG) (link found via [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322631/2577986)):

> In Android 4.3 these options moved from the "am" command (ActivityManager) to the "wm" command (WindowManager). Type "adb shell wm" for details.

So you can now run  on 4.3 devices:

`adb shell wm size 1280x800` or whatever size or `reset`

and

`adb shell wm density 480` or whatever density or `reset`

Just make sure the screen is not currently displaying at the moment you run the command.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is emulate a Tablet using Virtual Machine. I did a detailed tutorial based in other tutoriais, this is the link:

http://edwindh.blogspot.com/2014/07/emular-uma-tablet-ou-smartphone-com.html