# Load Mobile Android App on Nexus 7

Tags: android, mobile, tablet, nexus-7

Is there a simple enough method in loading a mobile app that is optimized for mobile resolutions on a Nexus 7?

I am looking to force an app that has a smaller resolution than the Nexus 7, example: 480x800 but without scaling the app layouts stretching to fill in the entire space of the Nexus 7.
To keep within a container that is 400x800.

Any help would be very very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Thinking like ios. You're doing it wrong.

Comment: Are you just trying to install an apk? If thats the case adb install should work just fine. The app should have been built with layouts to handle the resolution on devices as part of it's included resources.

Comment: The apk file scales in terms of the resolution of the nexus 7. What i would like is to keep it within a smaller resolution frame to mimic it being loaded on a mobile device.

Example on a resolution of 400x800

Comment: You may want to edit your question to be more explicit about your intent. The reference to IOS devices doesn't add that much detail about what you are trying to do. To my knowledge I don't currently know of a way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I updated the question. not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise trying it on emulator first to make sure it looks fine.

Alternatively if you have a device (like a Nexus 7) you can use `adb shell am display-size`

See: [how to resize physical android screen from terminal/shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451231/how-to-resize-physical-android-screen-from-terminal-shell)