# How to set a custom resolution on Android-x86 in VMware Player

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, android-x86, vmware-player

I want to run Android X86 9.0-r1 virtual machine in Full Hd resolution within Vmware Workstation Player 15.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Boot in debug mode (second option in boot menu)
2. When booting stops press 'Enter' and enter command `mount -o remount,rw /mnt`
3. Command `cd /mnt/grub`
4. Command `vi menu.lst`
5. Press 'i' to enter edit mode
6. Replace `quiet` parameter in first config with 'nomodeset xforcevesa video=1920x1080' or use own params.You can also add depth buffer like this `video=1280x720x32` or add dpi setting `video=1280x720x32 DPI=400`
7. Press 'Esc', type ':w', press 'Enter' to save.
8. Press 'Esc', type ':x', press 'Enter' to exit.
9. Type `reboot -f`

   Thats all!

Comment: This did not work for me with Android x86 version 7 on VirtualBox. Are vertical resolutions like 600x1040 supported? This is what I used to make an app like TikTok partially work on Anbox.

Update: I was able to change the resolution with the command `wm size 600x1040` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336026/how-to-deal-with-apps-that-force-screen-orientation-in-android-x86-on-virtualbox) but it did not fix the issue of TikTok crashing.

Answer (score 1):

If the android system is started press `Alt+F1`.

type in

```
mkdir /mnt/sda
mount /dev/block/sda1 /mnt/sda
vi /mnt/sda/grub/menu.lst
```

press `i` to edit, replace `quiet` to `nomodeset xforcevesa` if you have not done it until now. Because you can make sure, that it will boot. At the end of the line add `UVESA_MODE=yourdesiredresolution` as example `UVESA_MODE=1280x720`

press `Esc` to return read-mode
press `:w` then press `Enter`
press `:q` then press `Enter`
type `reboot` then press `Enter`

Unfortunately, I still have one remark: You cannot choose any resolution! I tried `3840x2160` because I want to use Android x86 on a smart table. Would have been nice. Too bad.