# enlarge the display area of Android x86 on VMWare

Tags: vmware, android-x86

good day,

so, I just installed Android x86 (LineageOS) on VMware and adjust display setting using following this thread

[How to set a custom resolution on Android-x86 in VMware Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576471/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution-on-android-x86-in-vmware-player). however, I can't figure how to display it in full screen on VMware, any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

When your android system has turned on
You have to press Alt and f1 keys together on your keyboard. It will open a terminal like Linux shell
Now enter these commands to edit configuration

```
mkdir /mnt/sda
mount /dev/block/sda1 /mnt/sda
vi /mnt/sda/grub/menu.lst
```

To edit press i key on the keyboard replace quiet to nomodeset xforcevesa if you have not done it until now. Because you can make sure, that it will boot. At the end of the line add UVESA_MODE=yourdesiredresolution as example UVESA_MODE=1280x720

Now enter these keys serial

Escape

:w

Enter

:q

Enter

Now type in reboot and press enter