# adb shell - How can I override the detected physical screen size

Tags: android, shell, adb, android-tv

I have mi box 3 (android tv v6.0.1) connected via hdmi/dvi converter to a monitor with resolution of 1680x1050.

The resolution gets detected as 1920x1080 and appears stretched on screen, I have tried to override it to 1680x1050 using command `adb shell wm size 1680x1050` but the resolution screen gets boxed..

```
nomo$ adb shell wm size
Physical size: 1920x1080
Override size: 1680x1050
```

I need to somehow adjust the physical size so screen appears perfectly proportional..

Comment: Try to use [**`adb shell am display-size`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#issuingcommands), example **`adb shell am display-size 1680x1050`**. See also this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451231/how-to-resize-physical-android-screen-from-terminal-shell) for reference.

Comment: I tried already, seems there is no such command anymore.